# ordinary expression

Tags: java

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print(">> ");
String line = kb.nextLine();

line = line.trim();
int i = 0;

do {
  int j = i;
  while ((!line.substring(j, j + 1).equals(" ")) && (j < line.length())) {
  //while ((j < line.length())&&(!line.substring(j, j + 1).equals(" "))) {
    j++;
  }
  System.out.println("-> " + line.substring(i, j));
  i = j;
  while ((line.substring(i, i + 1).equals(" "))&&(i<line.length())) {
  //while ((i < line.length()) && (line.substring(i, i + 1).equals(" "))) {

    i++;
  }
}while (i < line.length());
```

why expression ....

```
while ((!line.substring(j, j + 1).equals(" ")) && (j < line.length()))
```

not equal with

```
while ((j < line.length())&&(!line.substring(j, j + 1).equals(" ")))
```

Comment: because while using logical AND, if first operand in AND operation evaluates to false then next operand will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the string could be of length 0 in which case you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: or more specifically, when `j == line.length() - 1`, you try to get the substring using an index which is out of bounds.